# Do VS Code TestItems support multi-select actions?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I have built a Test Explorer extension for VS Code, and would like to support multi-select right click actions but I cannot figure out if this is supported, and if so how to implement it.

I have added a context menu via the package.json like this:

```
"testing/item/context": [
      {
        "submenu": "myTestExplorer,mySubmenu",
        "group": "myExtension"
      }
"myTestExplorer,mySubmenu": [
      {
        "command": "myExtension.myCommand"
      },
```

And have registered the command like this:

```
let myCommand = vscode.commands.registerCommand('myExtension.myCommand', (args: any) => {
    if (args) {
        doSomething(args.id);
    }
});
context.subscriptions.push(myCommand);
```

All of this works fine, but there does not seem to be the ability to add a second 'argList' parameter to the command as there is for the explorer view commands.

Comment: Does `(...args: any)` give you any more arguments?

Comment: That did it, now I get an array!  Thanks @Mark

Comment: Great, I'll put it into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```js
vscode.commands.registerCommand('myExtension.myCommand', (...args: any)
```

as a way to gather up all passed arguments using a `rest` parameter.  Particularly useful when you don't know exactly what may be passed.  And sometimes by examining the resultant `args` array you may be able to split the result (it looks like you may have already tried this) into two parameters or more.